# Is it possible to clean blob in chrome before the usage of storage over the limitation(500MB)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, blob

In the chrome extension, the process of the program will do record -> stop -> download infinitely. The recorded files aes saved as blob in Chrome after capture the mediastream and then download as wav file in the local device. During the procedure, I also set `revokeObjectURL()` to release the existed objectURL. (ref: [Javascript - File saved to disk is stuck in Chrome's memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878506/javascript-file-saved-to-disk-is-stuck-in-chromes-memory))

```js
var blob = mediaRecorder.blob;
if (callback) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    callback(url);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Before doing `revokeObjectURL()`, there were two kinds of data in `chrome://blob-internals`.

- type 1:

  ```
  02e068bb-33a0-4759-a085-a4850cb9259a
    -Refcount: 1
    -Content Type: audio/wav
    -Type: data
    -Length: 303,148
  ```
- type 2:

  ```
    blob:chrome-extension%3A//koexxkllffcmnhxlnhacmcnpjkcodngb//xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    - uuid: 02e068bb-33a0-4759-a085-a4850cb9259a
  ```

After doing `revokeObjectURL()`, type 2 does not be displayed anymore but type 1 is still there. Is there any other method to clean type 1 data properly? I also saw the information about Garbage Collection (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis#determine-garbage-collection-frequency), but I'm not sure whether GC runs before the storage of blob is over 500MB, which may cause the downloaded file shows "no file". In this stage, the usage of memory is increased slowly but I'm worry that may cause "out of memory" after the long run test.

Comment: I'm thinking that is it possible to set a global BLOB and use it in the local function. Thus, BLOB will be built only once and data can be inserted in the same BLOB every time. However, there is a problem I do not know how to fix: how to set Array in BLOB?